# Upgrading gradle issue from 2.3.3 to 3.5.1

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, androidx

Updating gradle version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

gradle wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
android.useAndroidX=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

showing error

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try deleting your .gradle folder.

Comment: done but not working

Comment: delete .gradle folder, .idea folder and every build folder. Then remove the open entry from the recently open project list. Then open the project by finding the path in file manager again. If this doesn't work delete the .gradle folder in with path ~/.gradle if you are using mac. ~ means home. Then repeat the above process.

Comment: I have done it, but not working.

Comment: Pls upgrade question for full details  in build.gradle